# User input into a two dimensional array

Tags: c#

I'm completely new to C# and well I would like simple code to create a matrix from user input

E.G.

```
int [,] matrix1 = new int [2,2]
// now using input i'd like to add integers into the array
matrix1[0,1] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // this is for user input
```

and so on.

Comment: So, Where is the problem?

Comment: @user2223460, you need to read about [loops in c#](http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/CSharp/Lesson04) and [loops with multidimensional arrays](http://www.dotnetperls.com/2d-array)

Comment: If I understand question.You need parse user input line and in loop add integers to array.

Answer (score 3):

```
var numbers = new int[size, size];

for (var i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    var numList = new string[size];
    numList = readLine.Split();
    for (var j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        numbers[i, j] = Convert.ToInt32(numList[j]);     
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried this and worked the way it was supposed to. please check and mark it as answered

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged here on SO. Can you add some explanation as to how this fixes the problem?

Answer (score 2):

```
int[,] A = new int[5, 4];

//read
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        A[i, j] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());  
    }
}

//Write
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine();

    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        Console.Write(A[i, j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   int[,] matrix1 = new int[2, 2];

   for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
   {
         for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
         {
            matrix1[i, j] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());  
         }
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
   {
          for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
          {
             Console.WriteLine("Element({0},{1})={2}", i, j, matrix1[i, j]);
          }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to find a good answer to that question in C#, I searched a lot until a friend helped me to understand how to do it with user input, SO I will leave the answer here maybe it could help anyone

```cs
int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); //the size of the array
int m = n;
int[,] arr = new int[n, m];
string[]lines = new string[n]; // so we could read the input from the user
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // here we need to read more than one line
{
    lines[i] = Console.ReadLine();
}


for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    string[]num = lines[i].Split(' ');
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        int z = Convert.ToInt32(num[j]);
        arr[i, j] = z;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine();
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        Console.Write(arr[i, j] + " ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter the height: ");
int h = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Enter the width: ");
string w = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

int[,] arr = new int[w, h];

for (int i = 0; i < w; ++i)
  for (int j = 0; j <h; ++j)
    arr[i, j] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

var numbers = new int[size, size];

```
            for (var i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                var numList = new string[size];
                numList = readLine.Split();
                for (var j = 0; j < size; j++)
                {
                    numbers[i, j] =convert.ToInt32(numList[j]);                        
                }
```

}