# How to input a complete 2D matrix using console in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix

I am trying to write a code in C# to input a 2D matrix where all the values of the matrix are entered at once. i.e all row and column values are passed in the console by a user.
The below code gives:

> Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

```
string[] lineSplitter = line.Split(' ');
row = long.Parse(lineSplitter[0]);
col = long.Parse(lineSplitter[1]);
long[,] a = new long[row,col];
for(i=0;i<row;i++){
   for(j=0;j<col;j++){
       a[i,j] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
   }
}

Console input from user ex: 
3 3
4 2 1
1 1 3
1 1 2
```

I guess I have to read the matrix using Console.ReadLine() and than split it. But how do I split it for both spaces and newline and also for variable row column sizes? Moreover ReadLine() won't read the whole matrix at once. It will read only one line of the matrix.

Comment: While I believe code you are looking for is present in a duplicate... there is a good chance that your question is actually totally different: "how to read multiple lines of input from console as single line in a single ReadXxxx method" (as an answer - to my knowledge does not exist).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this. Split the input and assign the col values.

```
        long row, col;
        string line = Console.ReadLine();
        string delim = " ";
        string[] lineSplitter = line.Split(delim);
        row = long.Parse(lineSplitter[0]);
        col = long.Parse(lineSplitter[1]);
        long[,] a = new long[row, col];
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        {
            string l = Console.ReadLine();
            string[] colValues = l.Split(delim);

            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            {

                a[i, j] = int.Parse(colValues[j]);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read line on row and use split values:

```
for(i = 0; i < row; i++) {
   String[] rowLine = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
   for(j = 0; j < col; j++) {
       a[i,j] = int.Parse(rowLine[j]);
   } 
}
```

Comment: Marginally better than https://stackoverflow.com/a/32770713/477420... I still think it is duplicate question.